# Delete the uploaded Excel file after bind the data source to gridview in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, gridview

I want to delete the excel and csv file after complete reading and bind data source to the grid view.. However after I successful deleted the file, my gridview has empty data...

```
DataTable dt = GetCsvData(_path, _filename);
gvList.DataSource = dt;
gvList.DataBind();      // before delete, gridview has data..
File.Delete(_path+_filename);    // after delete, gridview has empty data
```

Comment: Is this code on Page Load? You would want to do that only on first page Load

Comment: @andy It is asp.net web forms. Look at the `DataBind()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the file could not have any relation to the fact that your grid view is empty. Obviously the call to `GetCsvData` loads the entire file into a `DataTable` so there must be no harm on deleting the file.

Debug the code, and make sure after the call to `GetCsvData` the `dt` contains data.

If `dt` contains data, you are probably performing data binding in the wrong time. Put the code in `Page_Load`. If you do the binding in a later phase in the page life cycle, probably the data will not be rendered.

Comment: @Minimoma Then there is a problem with your binding. I don't have much information about data binding in web forms, but I'm sure about what I've said.

Comment: yes..@MD.Unicorn.. U r rite... I bind the code in page_Load.. It's really work! Thx a lot..

Comment: @Minimoma You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the check mark near the answer. Please read [faq] for more information.

Comment: yes.. I hav clicked dy.. but need 15 reputation... I have not enough reputation

Comment: @Minimoma I'm not talking about upvote (clicking the up arrow). Below the up and down arrow, there is a check mark. [This section of the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) describes accepting asnwers. Also see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/178969). This also gives some reputation to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
gvList.DataSource = dt.Copy();
```

Comment: Copy gives you a copy of your data table. So when you make changes to it, you don't affect the original. Also if the original is deleted , it doesn't bother you since you have a copy :)

Comment: I try to put the code in page_load.. Its solved my problem... I have tried this solution too.. But it seem like not work not work for me.. Maybe I'm using it by the wrong way... Anyway, thanks ya:)